# Синтаксическая ошибка в запросе

Tags: php, mysql

PHP:

```
$queryup='UPDATE posts SET name='.$_REQUEST["name"].', post='.$_REQUEST["post"].' 
WHERE id='.$_REQUEST["idpost"];

mysql_query($queryup)or die("error:" . mysql_error());
echo 'Готово'/n;
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Ответ:

> error:You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near '=
>
> 13fsdf WHERE id=20' at line 1

В чём дело?

Comment: пора принять ответ :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$queryup="UPDATE posts SET name='".$_REQUEST["name"]."', post='".$_REQUEST["post"]."' WHERE id='".$_REQUEST["idpost"]."';
```

Я бы так сделал.